# Thunderbird (python, Mac):Click send button

Tags: python, macos, email, thunderbird

I'm trying to automate sending emails with attachments via Thunderbird.  I can create a new email with the correct destination address, subject, body and attachment.  But I'm not sure how to send it.  All I need to do is click the send button.  I've messed around with DOM Inspector and it doesn't seem like the right direction.  Can anyone give me a hint? My code to create the emails is:

```
import os
os.system("/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/thunderbird -compose
'to=abc@abc.edu','subject=this subject','body=this is the 
body','attachment=/Users/Username/Desktop/test.txt'")
```

Answer (score 0):

"Thunderbird does not support automated sending, because a malicious program could use it to send mail without your knowledge. If you search the Internet you can easily find applications that send bulk mail. Alternatively, create a script that writes to Thunderbird's outbox file, then you can start Thunderbird and send all the unsent messages."

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1850025